# Unable to read csv file in Jupyter notebook from my PC local folder

Tags: dataframe, csv, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, read-csv

I tried reading a csv file from a local source on my pc but it was displaying the following:

sales = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/survey_results_public.csv')

---

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 1
----> 1 sales=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/survey_results_public.csv')

NameError: name 'pd' is not defined

```
I tried reading a csv file from a local source on my pc but it was unable to read the fiie.
```

```
Instead it would display:

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 1
----> 1 sales=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/survey_results_public.csv')  

NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to install pandas upfront (pip install pandas) and import it as pd before using its read_csv function.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/survey_results_public.csv')
```

Comment: Explicitly `%pip install pandas` if you are running that from inside your Jupyter `.ipynb` file. Then restart the kernel. See more about the magic versions of the install commands [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) that let you run them in the notebook and insure installation to the correct environment where the kernel is running that underlies the active `.ipynb` file.